# Как получить данные о новом почтовом сообщении в node-imap

Tags: javascript, node.js

Мне требуется получить информацию о новой почте в ивенте on mail через node-imap.
А именно:

- Почта, через которую было отправлено сообщение
- Заголовок сообщения
- И содержимое сообщение (текст)

Мой код на данный момент:

```js
let Imap = require('node-imap')

let imap = new Imap({
    user: '***@gmail.com',
    password: '***',
    host: 'imap.gmail.com',
    port: 993,
    tls: true
});
imap.on('ready', () => {
    imap.openBox('INBOX', true, (err, box) => {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        else console.log('Recipient is ready for accepting')
    })
})
imap.on('mail', mail => {
    const title = ?
    const subject = ?
    const email = ?
    console.log(`Email author: ${email} Title: ${title}, Description: ${subject}`)
})

imap.connect();
```